# Using Docker Buildkit on Azure with az acr build

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-buildkit

i'm looking for a way to use the docker buildkit with az acr build.
I know that its possible with azure pipeline but how to use it with the azure cli?

Regards,
Jürgen

Comment: Not the only one having this issue; https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/721